# Using SQL Between Query and Showing all results in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

this is my sample code to check the data on Table1 using 2 filters, column1 and between data in column2. The code I have is working but is only getting 1 result. So for example. I enter "1" in textbox1,  "3" in textbox2 and "6" in textbox3. `Select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN1 = '1' AND COLUMN2 BETWEEN '3' AND '6'`   -- when run in sql result is 3,4,5,6 but in C# I am only getting "6". Can you help me with this to get "3,4,5,6" as a result. Thank you.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    SqlConnection SC;
    SqlCommand CMD;
    SqlDataReader DR;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SC = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BABBLER"].ConnectionString);
        SC.Open();
        CMD = new SqlCommand("Select * from TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1= '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and  COLUMN2 Between '" + TextBox2.Text + "'" + " and " + "'" + TextBox3.Text + "'", SC);

        DR = CMD.ExecuteReader();

        if (DR.HasRows)
        {
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = DR["COLUMN2"].ToString();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of composing your sql statement like that or you might get a visit from [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
label1.Text = DR["COLUMN2"].ToString();
```

as

```
label1.Text = label1.Text +", " + DR["COLUMN2"].ToString();
if (Label1.Text.Length > 2)
   Label1.Text = Label1.Text.Substring(2);
```

Comment: Thank you but this code will show data without commas ",". Result is 3 4 5 6 should be 3,4,5,6

Comment: Concatenating strings in a loop should be avoided - it is [slow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is not appending the values, rather overwriting Label1. Change your while loop to

```
while (DR.Read())
{
   label1.Text += DR["COLUMN2"].ToString() + ",";
}

if (label1.Text.EndsWith(",")) label1.Text = label1.Text.SubString(0, label1.Text.Length-1) //Remove the last comma
```

Comment: Thank very much Arun. It now shows 3 4 5 6 but no comma. How can I add the commas? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need brackets around the expression. label1.Text += (DR["COLUMN2"].ToString() + ",");

Comment: I tried but still showing 3 4 5 6 as an output. Commas are nowhere to find. Thank you for the answering. Such a relief.

Comment: Am surprised. You may need to debug by putting a break point inside the loop and watch the label1.Text in your immediate window. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
SC = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BABBLER"].ConnectionString);
SC.Open();
CMD = new SqlCommand("Select * from TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1= '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and  COLUMN2 Between '" + TextBox2.Text + "'" + " and " + "'" + TextBox3.Text + "'", SC);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD);
da.Fill(ds);

string data="";
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++ )
{

   if(data=="")
   {
      label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN2"].ToString();
   }
   else
   {
      label1.Text +=","+ ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN2"].ToString();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods to combine results into a comma-separated list.  However, using string concatenation should not be one - [concatenating strings is slow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822), especially if you might have a large number of results.  Try one of the following instead:

Using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean doneFirstRow = false;
while (DR.READ())
{
    if (doneFirstRow) 
    {
        sb.Append(", ");
    }
    else 
    {
        doneFirstRow = true;
    }
    sb.Append(dr["COLUMN2"].ToString());
}
Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Using a List with [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx):

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
while (DR.READ())
{
    values.Add(dr["COLUMN2"].ToString());
}
Label1.Text = String.Join(", ", values);
```

NB: If not using NET4.5 you'll need `String.Join(", ", values.ToArray())`